# Thumbnail grid expandable data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I was using a plugin of sorts located here to pull this off. I have been working on this page for a few hours wen I checked with my client. He stated that he does not want me to use a plugin. He referenced the jQuery Animate but I am such a noob to writing my own code I am not sure where to start with all that. I included an image of what I need it to do and look like but I need some help finding a solution. Thank you for all your help and time!)

I need to add that the description will always expand directly under the leaders thumbnail. I would like it to be seemless for mobile users as well. If possible?

[image]

```
    <div class="container leaderShipwrapper gallery-items">
        <ul id="items" class="row list-unstyled">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-1 leaderShipgrid">
                <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="joe" data-title="developer" data-profile="profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="ray" data-title="dunce" data-profile="dunce profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="joe" data-title="developer" data-profile="profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="joe" data-title="developer" data-profile="profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 leader" data-name="joe" data-title="developer" data-profile="profile"><a href="#"><img class="image-responsive" src="images/leader.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <li id="1" class="leaderDescription"><div class="leaderName">NAME</div><div class="leaderTitle">TITLE</div><div class="leaderProfile">Description for row 1 cell 1</div></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
            $('.leader').click(function(){
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.leaderDescription').find('.leaderName').text($(this).attr('data-name'));
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.leaderDescription').find('.leaderTitle').text($(this).attr('data-title'));
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.leaderDescription').find('.leaderProfile').text($(this).attr('data-profile'));
$(this).parent().siblings().find('.leaderDescription').slideDown();
});
</script>
```

Ok, so I have this at a good point to ask this question now. I need to know what I need to do to get this closer to the image above. I have the first row and I am getting the data to load correctly I just cant get the slide up if one is already open then slide down the new one that was clicked. I also need it to open the info below the leaders photo like the in the photo I added. Please let me know how far I am from this?

Comment: Here is a bootply I created to help and show where I am at

http://www.bootply.com/lx8uLN7vWW

Answer (score 0):

I might approach this such that the container expands on click, not hover, so as to set this up for consistent behaviour with mobile.

Give all of your expandable containers the same classname (eg: `employeeDetails`).

Give all of your photo tiles a class name as well (eg: `employeeThumb`).  Then set up a click event for your photo tiles:

```
$(".employeeThumb"_.on("click touchstart", function() {
  $(".employeeThumb").slideUp(105);   //closes any open expanded items
  $(this).find('.hover-dropdown').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(150);
}
```

You could modify the above such that it detects whether the current one is already open, and just closes it.

Comment: ohh jeez I added some code that is not supposed to be in there. Ill edit this now. Sorry